# How do i redirect back to the login page after 10 seconds of inactivity using django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

In my settings.py I state this and the sessionId did expire but it redirect me to some random links that I never state at all instead back to the login page and will show some error, I want it to redirect back to the login page after 10 seconds of inactivity, how do I do that?

My settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',


]

    SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 10  
    
    SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True
    
    SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

My views.py

```
 def login_view(request):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        msg = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')  # retrieve the username
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')  # retrieve the password
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  # authenticate user
    
                if user is not None and user.is_admin:  # authenticated if user is an admin
                    login(request, user)
    
    
                    return redirect('adminpage')  # redirect the user to the admin page
    
                elif user is not None and user.is_customer:  # authenticated if user is a customer service
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('customer')  # redirect the user to the customer service page
    
                elif user is not None and user.is_logistic:  # # authenticated if user is a logistic
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('logistic')  # redirect the user to the logistic page
                else:
                    msg = 'invalid credentials'
    
            else:
                msg = 'error validating form'
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form, 'msg': msg})
def admin(request):

    return render(request, 'admin.html')
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login_view'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('adminpage/', views.admin, name='adminpage'),
    path('customer/', views.customer, name='customer'),
    path('logistic/', views.logistic, name='logistic'),
    path('forget/', views.forget, name='forget'),
    path('newblock/', views.newblock, name='newblock'),
    path('quote/', views.quote, name='quote'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('adminprofile/', views.adminprofile, name='adminprofile'),
]
```

This is the error message it show me after the session expire:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about your login url :

Django try to redirect on `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/` but this url is not defined in any `urls.py` file.

Add `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('login_view')` in the `settings.py` file. (don't forgot `from django.urls import reverse_lazy`).

Comment: Can you mark this answer that it resolve your issue. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware' calls `django.contrib.auth.views.redirect_to_login` if you are not provided `SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT`  value in your settings. [Details](https://github.com/labd/django-session-timeout/blob/a64d96f4219188d596c914f3bf25c469e5677f9a/src/django_session_timeout/middleware.py#L31)

`redirect_to_login` internally uses `settings.LOGIN_URL` value https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#login-url

Looks like you have two options: set SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT or change LOGIN_URL value in your settings. I'd recommend to change the second one.

Comment: I see, let me try and will get back to you

Comment: Nice background. Changing LOGIN_URL worked for me. Thanks!